# How can I fix these errors about lottery winning game

Tags: java, string

I created a lottery winning game but I got these errors but can't fix them, I need help with fix it.

```
package LotteryGame;
public class StartGame {
 public static WinningNumber winning;
 public static User userNum;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  winning = new WinningNumber();
  userNum = new User();
  String winningNumber = winning.generateWinningNumber();
  System.out.println("=======================MAX LOTTO=======================");
  System.out.println(winningNumber);
  String usersLotteryNumber = User.askUser();
  determineWinner(winningNumber, usersLotteryNumber);
 }
 public static void determineWinner(String winningNumber, String usersLotteryNumber) {
   if (usersLotteryNumber.equals(winningNumber)) {
    System.out.println("Congratulations, YOU Win!");
   } else {
    System.out.println("Sorry, you might win next time");
   }
   String userNumber;
   public User() {
    userNumber = "What is your Lottery Number?";
   }
   public static String askUser() {
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your lottery number: ");
    String userNumber = user_input.next();
    return userNumber;
    package LotteryGame;
    import java.util.Random;
    String winningNumber;
    public WinningNumber() {
     winningNumber = "";
    }
    public String generateWinningNumber() {
     Random rand = new Random();
     winningNumber = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(9999999));
     return winningNumber;
    }
   }
```

**These are the errors  I have, im not sure how to fix them, I as many I could but troubling with these ones**

```
15 errors found:
File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\College\LotteryGame\StartGame.java  [line: 38]
Error: illegal start of expression
File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\College\LotteryGame\StartGame.java  [line: 38]
Error: ';' expected
File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\College\LotteryGame\StartGame.java  [line: 45]
Error: illegal start of expression
File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\College\LotteryGame\StartGame.java  [line: 45]
Error: illegal start of expression
File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\College\LotteryGame\StartGame.java  [line: 45]
Error: ';' expected
File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\College\LotteryGame\StartGame.java  [line: 45]
Error: ';' expected
File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\College\LotteryGame\StartGame.java  [line: 52]
Error: illegal start of expression
File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\College\LotteryGame\StartGame.java  [line: 52]
Error: not a statement
File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\College\LotteryGame\StartGame.java  [line: 54]
Error: illegal start of expression
File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\College\LotteryGame\StartGame.java  [line: 54]
Error: not a statement
File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\College\LotteryGame\StartGame.java  [line: 57]
Error: illegal start of expression
File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\College\LotteryGame\StartGame.java  [line: 57]
Error: ';' expected
File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\College\LotteryGame\StartGame.java  [line: 64]
Error: illegal start of expression
File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\College\LotteryGame\StartGame.java  [line: 64]
Error: ';' expected
File: C:\Users\User\Desktop\College\LotteryGame\StartGame.java  [line: 73]
Error: reached end of file while parsing
```

Comment: You seems to have randomized some lines. `package` line should be the first one, then come the `import` lines.

Comment: Please read the errors and try figuring it by yourself first. This will be your best school.

Comment: why do you have User and WinningNumber as static in your main class ? read the error. you havnt closed the function on line 38

Answer (score 2):

This is what happens when you don't format your code in a way you can understand.

Anyway this is just pure chaos.

You have a package definition and an import in the middle of the class, you're missing at the very least one } for the determineWinner method and if WinningNumber is a constructor, then you need a class for that. Which can't be in the same file.

And those are just the things I see without really looking. Just clean up your code and all your errors will go away (probably).

Comment: He has no idea what he's doing, cleaning up is going to be hard.